# How to hide buttons from updatemenus in plotly python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I want to create a dynamic chart with Plotly in Python -> change the style options via buttons in the graph itself. Therefore, plotly offers buttons or drowdownmenus (updatemenus). My current problem is, that I would like to hide some of these buttons depending on which one is active.

My example is a plot where I can change my graph from lines into markers (first button set) and as special option for the lines I offer dotted, dashed and solid line (second button set). 
Obviously, offering the second button set when "Markers" is active doesn't make sense. So I would like to hide the second set. But until now I didn't find a solution.
I am using the offline version of plotly.

I would appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

My mini example:

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10]
y_ = [1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 1.35, 1.3]

trace_ = go.Scatter(
    x = x_,
    y = y_,
    mode = "lines",
    line = dict(
        dash = "dot"
    )
)

layout_ = go.Layout(
    autosize = True
)

updatemenus_ = list([
    dict(
        buttons = list([
            dict(
                args=['mode', 'lines'],
                label='Lines',
                method='restyle'
            ),
            dict(
                args=['mode', 'markers'],
                label='Markers',
                method='restyle'
            )
        ]),
        direction = 'left',
        pad = {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive = True,
        type = 'buttons',
        x = 0.1,
        xanchor = 'right',
        y = 1.1,
        yanchor = 'top'
    ),
    dict(
        buttons = list([
            dict(
                args=['line', {'dash': 'dot'}],
                label='Dotted Line',
                method='restyle'
            ),
            dict(
                args=['line', {'dash': 'dash'}],
                label='Dashed Line',
                method='restyle'
            ),
            dict(
                args=['line', {'dash': 'solid'}],
                label='Solid Line',
                method='restyle'
            )
        ]),
        direction = 'right',
        pad = {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive = True,
        type = 'buttons',
        x = 0.5,
        xanchor = 'right',
        y = 1.1,
        yanchor = 'top'
    ),
])

layout_['updatemenus'] = updatemenus_

fig = dict(data=[trace_], layout=layout_)

py.offline.plot(fig, filename='MiniExample.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the visibility of the buttons, you need to rely on "Dash" module.
However, in the current example, I suggest to simply use "dropdown" type to toggle between different visualization of the graph.
A quick example based on your need:

```
x_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10]
y_ = [1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 1.35, 1.3]

f = go.Scatter(
    x = x_,
    y = y_,
    mode = "markers",
    )

fig = go.Figure(f)

buttons = [{"method":'restyle', "args": [{"mode": "markers"}], "label": "Markers"},
           {"method": "restyle", "args":[{"mode": "lines",  "line.dash": "solid"}], "label": "solid_line"},
           {"method": "restyle", "args":[{"mode": "lines", "line.dash": "dot"}], "label": "dotted_line"}, 
           {"method": "restyle", "args":[{"mode": "lines", "line.dash": "dash"}], "label": "dashed_line"},
           ]


updatemenus = [{"type": "dropdown", "buttons":buttons, "x":0.12, "y": 1.2, "showactive":True}]
 
annotations=[dict(text="Graph format:", showarrow=False, x=1, y=1.3, yref="paper", align="right")]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus, annotations=annotations)
fig.show()
```

[image: The outcome of the script]
I hope you find it helpful.